# efficient way of accessing opencv Mat elements

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to play around with some OpenCV and thought up an interesting little scenario to work on.

Basically, I want to take a pixel, add the colour values from the 3 neighbouring pixels (so (x, y), (x+1, y) (x, y+1) and (x+1, y+1)) and divide the result by 4 to get an average colour value. Then the next set of pixels I process is (x+2, y+2) with it's 3 neighbours.

I then also want to be able to do a similar thing, but with 9 pixels (with the chosen co-ordinate to work from being the centre).

Initially I started with a gaussian blur type masking, but that's not the result I want to acheive. As from those calculations, I just want to get 1 pixel value. So the output image will be 1/4 or a 1/9 of the size. So for now I've got it working where I've literally written out the calculation in a for loop as:

```
for (int i = 1; i < myImage.rows -1; i++)
{
    b = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < myImage.cols -1; k++)
    {
        //9 pixel radius
        Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[1] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k-1)[1]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k)[1]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i+1, k)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[1]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k-1)[1]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k+1)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k+1)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k + 1)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k - 1)[1]) / 9;
        Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[2] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k-1)[2]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k)[2]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i+1, k)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[2]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k-1)[2]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k+1)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k+1)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k + 1)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k - 1)[2]) / 9;
        Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[0] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k-1)[0]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k)[0]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i+1, k)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[0]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k-1)[0]+myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k+1)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k+1)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i-1, k + 1)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k - 1)[0]) / 9;

        //4 pixel radius
        //      Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[1] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k + 1)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k - 1)[1] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i - 1, k)[1]) / 5;
        //      Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[2] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k + 1)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k - 1)[2] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i - 1, k)[2]) / 5;
        //      Result.at<Vec3b>(a, b)[0] = (myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i + 1, k)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k + 1)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i, k - 1)[0] + myImage.at<Vec3b>(i - 1, k)[0]) / 5;
        b++;
    }
    a++;
}
```

Obviously, it's possible to setup the two options as different function that is called, but I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way of achieveing this, that would let the size of the mask be changed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It sounds like you're just talking about resizing the image with linear interpolation.

Comment: Is your intention to achieve this the most efficient way with opencv, or do you want to learn to how to efficient pixel access with opencv?

Comment: My intention is mainly opencv related on finding an easier way of being able to change the number of pixels that are used to create the output.rather than just have to write it all out, it'd be nice to be able to use an input algorithm. Rather than just a long list of handwritten code to do a different set of inputs.

Comment: So how does [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) not meet your needs? Are you trying to avoid built-in methods? Also see http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv

Comment: The idea is to actually access a raw image, interpret the values of the raw red/blue/green pixels and try a variety of different cluster sizes to compare the outcome. Resize will have it's way of working, but I want to experiment with different ways of calculating a particular pixels output value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to do this all without built-in functions (like `resize`, `mean`, or `filter2d`) and just want to directly address the image using `at`. There are further optimizations that can be made, but this is intended as a reasonable and understandable improvement on the original code.

Also, it should be noted that I ignore any extra rows/columns when the image size is not exactly divisible by the scale factor. You'll need to specify the expected behavior if you want something different.

The first thing I'd do is change what you think of as the target pixel. Assume you have a 3x3 neighborhood like so:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

We're going to take the mean value of all of these pixels anyway, so whether we call pixel `5` the target or pixel `1` makes no difference to the resulting image. I'm going to call pixel `1` the target because it makes the math cleaner.

The `1` pixel will always be on coordinates divisible by the scaling factor. If the scaling factor is 2, the coordinates of `1` will always be even.

Second, rather than loop over the original image dimensions, which actually results in recalculating the same pixel in `Result` numerous times, I'm going to loop over the dimensions of `Result` and figure out which pixels in the original image contribute to each pixel in the result.

So to find neighborhood in the original image that corresponds to pixel `(x, y)` in the result image, we just have to look for pixel `1` of that neighborhood. Since it's a multiple of the scaling factor, it's just

```
(x * scaleFactor, y * scaleFactor)
```

Finally, we need to add two more nested loops to loop over the `scaleFactor x scaleFactor` window. This is the part the avoids having to type out those long calculations.

In the 3x3 example above, for example, pixel `9` in the neighborhood of `(x, y)` will be:

```
(x * scaleFactor + 2, y * scaleFactor + 2)
```

I also do the mean calculation directly in a vector rather than doing each channel individually. This means that our results will overflow a `uchar`, so I use `Vec3i` and cast it back to a `Vec3b` after the division. This is one place where you should consider using a built-in function `mean` to calculate the average over the window as it will remove the need for these new loops.

So, if our original image is `myImage`, we have:

```
int scaleFactor = 3;

Mat Result(myImage.rows/scaleFactor, myImage.rows/scaleFactor, 
           myImage.type(), Scalar::all(0));

for (int i = 0; i < Result.rows; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < Result.cols; k++)
    {
        // make sum an int vector so it can hold
        //  value = scaleFactor x scaleFactor x 255
        Vec3i areaSum = Vec3i(0,0,0);
        for (int m = 0; m < scaleFactor; m++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < scaleFactor; n++)
            {
                areaSum += myImage.at<Vec3b>(i*scaleFactor+m, k*scaleFactor+n);
            }
        }

        Result.at<Vec3b>(i,k) = Vec3b(areaSum/(scaleFactor*scaleFactor));
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of samples...

Original:

[image]

scaleFactor = 2:

[image]

scaleFactor = 3:

[image]

scaleFactor = 5:

[image]